# React-Native WebView Prevents onPress on Parent TouchableOpacity

Tags: react-native, webview, expo

i can expect, that in normal use you would want the touch events on a `WebView` to stay within the `WebView`, but in my case, i am using the `WebView` to draw some text with css (because i am unable to achieve this with the react-native stylesheet).

### The Problem

in this code the `WebView` component is commented out, and when i press on the "hello world" text, the function `console.log('onPress called.')` is called; but if i uncomment the `WebView`, the touch event is never called.

is there a way to prevent the `WebView` from taking the onPress event?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, WebView } from 'react-native';

...


            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => console.log('onPress called.')}
            >
                {/* <WebView
                    source={{
                        html: `
                            <h1
                                style="
                                    font-family: 'Impact';
                                    color: white;
                                    font-size: 25px;
                                    text-align: center;
                                    letter-spacing: 1px;
                                    -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
                                    -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
                                "
                            >
                                HELLO WORLD from this
                            </h1>
                        `
                    }}
                    style={{
                        // position: 'absolute',
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100
                    }}
                /> */}

                <Text
                    style={{
                        position: 'absolute',
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        top: 100,
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100
                    }}
                >hello world</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

### Update:

i have tried to prevent pointer events as suggested by user ValdaXD.

in this example when `pointerEventsNone` is set to `false`, the text will be clickable, but if `pointerEventsNone` is `true`, it will render the `WebView` and clicking on the `WebView` will not call the parent onPress event.

```
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback
                onPress={() => console.log({ isEditing: !isEditing })}
            >
                    {!!pointerEventsNone ? (<View pointerEvents="none" style={{ height: 100, width: 200 }}>
                            <WebView
                                javaScriptEnabled={true}
                                injectedJavaScript={`document.body.addEventListener('click', 
                                    function(e){
                                    window.postMessage("Message from WebView","*");
                                    console.log(e);
                                })`}
                                onMessage={e => console.log("message", e)}
                                source={{
                                    html: `
                                        <html>
                                        <body>
                                        <h1
                                            style="
                                                font-family: 'Impact';
                                                color: white;
                                                font-size: 25px;
                                                text-align: center;
                                                letter-spacing: 1px;
                                                -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
                                                -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
                                            "
                                        >
                                            HELLO WORLD from this
                                        </h1>
                                        </body>
                                        </html>
                                    `
                                }}
                                useWebKit
                                style={{
                                    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                                    width: 200,
                                    height: 100,
                                    flex: 1
                                }}
                            />


                        </View>)
                        : (<Text>hello world</Text>)
                    }
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, what I did is replaced the **TouchableOpacity** with **TouchableWithoutFeedback** and created a view using the same style as a parent have and just added extra **position: 'absolute'** and used a state and touchable methods like below:

```
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
           
          }} onPressIn={()=>{
            this.setState({boolState:true})
          }} onPressOut={()=>{
            this.setState({boolState:false})
          }}
          >
    <View style={parentStyle}>
    {boolState && <View style={[parentStyle,{
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor:'rgba(0,0,0,0.48)',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                top: 0,
                bottom:0,
                right:0,
                marginTop:0,
                padding:0}]}/>}
    -------------------------
    -------------------------
    </View>
    </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

Answer (score -1):

Yeah, you should wrap the webview in a view with pointerEvents ='none'

```
<View style={{...}} pointerEvents="none">
        <WebView .../>
        </View>
```

Comment: this does not work for me: `<View pointerEvents="none" style={{ height: 200, width: 200}}><WebView ... /></View>`

Comment: you should make the view absolute, not the webview . use style={{flex:1}} in the webview to fill all the view , and give the view style={{
                        // position: 'absolute',
                        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                        width: 200,
                        height: 100
                    }}

Comment: i have tried wrapping inside a  `<Text>hello wolrd</Text>` and it seems like the `pointerEvents="none"` prevents onPress events when pressing on that element, but i would like to trigger the onPress event on the parent `TouchableOpacity` instead, but it seems that that `pointerEvents="none" prevents bubbling up touch events.

Comment: Yeah.. so ... wrap the view inside a touchableopacity... -.-

Comment: i think i have did it exactly as you have described, but this still does not seem to work for me. i will update the question with an example.

Comment: Ok you want to be able to interact with the webview and at the same time detect  when the user touches the webview?

Comment: yes. to be more clear, i want the `WebView` to behave like a button.

Comment: Oh then you can add an event listener in your webview javascript, and in the webview use onMessage as an onPress event . Related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52738974/how-to-detect-tapped-word-in-webview

Comment: this does not work either. looking at the documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/webview) it seems like it should work, so maybe i am doing something wrong. but i am testing this on a vanilla setup of create-react-native-app. i have updated the example in the main question. you can see in the html content, i also added a few more html tags to make the html valid for the `document.body` selector used in the injected javascript.